# How can I sort the following sequence of strings in c++?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, sorting

So, I am solving a question which involves sorting a given sequence of proper strings composed of opening and closing brackets. An n parentheses sequence consists of n `"("`s and n `")"`s.

A valid parentheses sequence is defined as the following:

You can find a way to repeat erasing adjacent pair of parentheses `"()"` until it becomes empty.

For example, `"(())"` is a valid parentheses, you can erase the pair on the 2nd and 3rd position and it becomes `"()"`, then you can make it empty.
`")()("` is not a valid parentheses. Now, I want to know how can I sort the generated sequence of parentheses of a given length such that those strings which have the maximum opening brackets come in beginning and if two strings have same number of opening brackets in beginning, then, on traversing both the strings, whichever has the first opening bracket will be printed first. For example, for `n=3`, the sorted sequence will be,

```
((()))  // 3 opening in a row and hence first

(()()) // 2 opening (same as the one which is below this one) but has a opening bracket first

(())()

()(())

()()()
```

Comment: Do these strings contain anything other than parentheses?

Comment: No. These strings contain only paranthesis.

Comment: I think you'll just need to define an ordering and figure out which permutation the current string is. Then use that number for sorting.

Comment: use a sorting algorithm. essentially what's left is the comparison of two strings, which is really easy... what's your question?

Comment: A would ask [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) But it seems that the answer is "Nothing".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the standard sorting algorithm, [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

The default (lexicographical) ordering will achieve exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something but I think a straight sort will work. Its a bit like binary numbers except with `'('` and `')'` instead of `1`s and `0`s.

```
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> tests =
{
    "((()))",
    "(()())",
    "(())()",
    "()(())",
    "()()()"
};

int main()
{
    std::shuffle(tests.begin(), tests.end(),
        std::default_random_engine(std::random_device{}()));

    std::cout << "\nbefore:\n";
    for(auto const& s: tests)
        std::cout << s << '\n';

    // normal sort
    std::sort(tests.begin(), tests.end());

    std::cout << "\nafter:\n";
    for(auto const& s: tests)
        std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

**Example Output:**

```
before:
(()())
(())()
()()()
((()))
()(())

after:
((()))
(()())
(())()
()(())
()()()
```